# Javascript does not run on local page

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a very simple webextension that is supposed to open a local page in a new window when a button is clicked:

```
function openMyPage() {
    var popupURL = chrome.extension.getURL("my-page.html");

    chrome.windows.create({
      url: popupURL,
      type: "popup",
      height: 200,
      width: 200
    });
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(openMyPage);
```

Inside my-page.html I want to run some javascript but I can't get it to work. Even a simple script does not execute:

```
<html>
   <body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("JS executed")
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

The URL of the opened page is something along the lines of `moz-extension://8974747a-3aa7-4654-93e5-ad60d3de0cc5/my-page.html`. I've tried disabling addons such as NoScript, but to no avail.

How can I execute JS on this page? What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Edit: manifest.json as per request:

```
{

  "description": "Adds browser action icon to toolbar to open packaged web page. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Examples#open-my-page-button",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "open-my-page",
  "version": "1.0",
  "homepage_url": "https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/open-my-page-button",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/page-48.png"
  },

  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "open-my-page-button@mozilla.org",
      "strict_min_version": "45.0"
    }
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/page-32.png"
  }

}
```

It it taken directly from one of Mozilla's examples.

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: There are some limitations in the JS you can execute in an extension, check this doc https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

Comment: Please provide your *manifest.json* file. We need a *complete* [mcve] in order to be able to duplicate the problem.

Comment: @Dario This seems to be the right trail. The example on that page is almost exactly what I am trying to do. I'll give it a read, thanks.

Comment: What does the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (Ctrl-Shift-J, or Cmd-Shift-J on OSX) show wen you try to open your page.  I would guess that it shows something like: `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“script-src moz-extension://nnnnnnnn-nnnn-nnnn-nnnn-nnnnnnnnnnnn”).          my-page.html`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Inline scripts don't work with the Default Content Security Policy

You are probably running into the [Default Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy#Default_content_security_policy) which is:

```
"script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';"
```

Which means that [Inline JavaScript won't run](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy#Inline_JavaScript). In other words things like following are not permitted in your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> document.write("JS executed")</script>
```

or

```
<script>console.log("foo");</script>
```

or

```
<div onclick="console.log('click')">Click me!</div>
```

**Normal solution:**
The normal solution is to move all your JavaScript into one, or more, separate files and include them with something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-page.js"></script>
```

**Using inline scripts:**
If you desire to use inline scripts, you can use the [`content_security_policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy) key in your [*manifest.json*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json) file.  However, you will need to supply a "[hash of the script in the "script-src" directive.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/CR-CSP2-20150721/#script-src-hash-usage)"

Unless, for some reason, you really *need* to use inline scripts, you will probably find it *much* easier to move all of your script content to an external file rather than include scripts inline with your HTML (which would require you to recompute the hash for any change to the script).

**Implemented in Firefox 48:**
This Content Security Policy was [implemented in Firefox 48](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/04/29/webextensions-in-firefox-48/).  That blog post regarding Firefox 48 makes sure to mention:

> **Please note:** this will be a **backwards incompatible change** for any Firefox WebExtensions that did not adhere to this CSP. Existing WebExtensions that do not adhere to the CSP will need to be updated.

### **Your specific case:**

It will work if you change your script to (whitespace counts when creating the hash):

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("JS executed");</script>
```

And, add the following line to your *manifest.json*:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-Z4nYjltJ/RciFs77n2n91dzwoz1Qg/1JFwU5ODwWPC8='; object-src 'self';"
```

Comment: @s3rius, updated with how you can use inline scripts, if you *really* want to.

Comment: That does the trick, thanks. Annoying that I didn't find out about this myself, but google was frustratingly useless since questions to the extend of "javascript doesn't work in local pages" return a million things, none of which were relevant.

Comment: @s3rius, I'm glad I was able to help. The way I found it was to actually try it while looking in the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (Ctrl-Shift-J, or Cmd-Shift-J on OSX).  Once I had the error message I mentioned in in my comment on your question, searching for the problem was relatively easy.  The Browser Console is often quite helpful (although sometimes there is too much information from other add-ons/Firefox which has to be filtered out).

Comment: Indeed, I didn't even know that console existed prior to asking this question. My knowledge about web stuff wouldn't even fill a teaspoon :)

Comment: I was a bit confused about how to generate the hash.  1) Everything BETWEEN the tags, e.g. `document.write("JS executed");` 2) save it to a file e.g. `foo.txt`, with no end of line character, using a text editor that won't force add a line ending.  If using end of line character(s), make sure they're of the same type. 3) `openssl dgst -sha256 -binary foo.txt | openssl base64` which outputs `Z4nYjltJ/RciFs77n2n91dzwoz1Qg/1JFwU5ODwWPC8=`, the desired sha256 hash, base64 encoded from the binary, NOT the hexadecimal.  OpenSSL is available on most platforms, but other tools may exist.